# Select specific string allowing for minor misspelling

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a lot of german street names. Most of them end with the word `...strasse`. I want to replace `strasse` with its abreviation `str` allowing for minor misspellings (1 or 2 characters missing or wrong) such as `strae` or `strassee`.

I tried many things and looked up some more:

```
street_names <- c("GERBERSTRAE", "NEUE STRAASSE", "SCHLOSSSTASSE", "HAUPTSTRASSE", "WINZERGASSE")

> gsub("[STRASSE]{5,7}S?T?R?A?S?S?E?$" , "STR", street_names, perl = T)
[1] "GERBSTR"     "NEUE STR"    "SCHLOSTR"    "HAUPSTR"     "WINZERGASSE"

> gsub("S?T?R?A?S?S?E?$" , "STR", street_names, perl = T)
[1] "GERBERSTR"    "NEUE STRASTR" "SCHLOSSSTR"   "HAUPTSTR"    
[5] "WINZERGSTR"
```

But so far all of them get some right and some wrong, and I don't know how to combine them. ("Winzergasse" should not be matched, as it ends on `Gasse` which translates to alley)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

more examples

```
street_names <- c("GERBERSTRAE", "NEUE STRAASSE", "SCHLOSSSTASSE", "HAUPTSTRASSE", "LINDENSASSE",
                  "WINZERGASSE", "PARKSTRASE", "ALTE STTRASSE", "BACHSTRAS", "LANGE SRASS")
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at the `stringdist` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
gsub("GASSE(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|ST*R?[ASE]+$", "STR", street_names, perl = T)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "GERBERSTR"   "NEUE STR"    "SCHLOSSSTR"  "HAUPTSTR"    "WINZERGASSE"
```

---

The pattern here is

```
GASSE(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match "GASSE" and let it fail
|                   # or
ST*R?[ASE]+         # S, T (0 or more times), R (optional), any A, S or E
$                   # end of the string
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vDbVrR/2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many different types of typografic errors you can encounter. For the examples you have given, something like this would work:

```
gsub("STR.*|STA.*","STR",street_names)
[1] "GERBERSTR"   "NEUE STR"    "SCHLOSSSTR"  "HAUPTSTR"   
[5] "WINZERGASSE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending a question mark to every character in the pattern makes them all optional, so the pattern will basically match everything.
It's much easier to just list common misspellings fully and live with the fact that some people will find creative spellings that you didn't think of.

Answer (score 0):

A bit brute force, but save I think:

```
gsub("(STRAE$)|(STRAASSE$)|(STASSE$)|(STRASSE$)", "STR", street_names)
[1] "GERBERSTR"   "NEUE STR"    "SCHLOSSSTR"  "HAUPTSTR"    "WINZERGASSE"
```